# Changing TinyMCE valid_elements and valid_children properties

Tags: wysiwyg

I'm trying to get TinyMCE + WYSIWYG + D7 to produce HTML like this...

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>Foo</h2>
        <p>bar</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[According to my tests](http://jsfiddle.net/VyTfV/), TinyMCE can do this easily out of the box. Just create the list. Type some text, highlight **Foo** and select the **Heading 2** format.

However, when I perform the same actions in Drupal, TinyMCE will change the entire contents of the `<li>` to be the selected format... producing markup like this...

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>Foo<br/>
        bar</h2>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I expect this is because Drupal is setting the `valid_children` or `valid_elements` properties of TinyMCE but I dont see how to affect them in the configuration page.

How do I change Drupals config for these? How do I get the editor to produce the markup that I want?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about WYSIWYG+TinyMCE in Drupal 7...the only mention of `valid_children` or `valid_elements` is in wysiwyg/editors/tinymce.inc. You can probably make your changes there, I don't see any alter hooks provided by WYSIWYG

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the ambiguity. I will add that to the question.